# Why am I not be able to post json array from Azure Function activity at Azure Data Factory?

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I have created Azure Function activity on Azure Data Factory.
The Azure Function activity calls a function of Azure Function App (Python, App Service Plan).

The Python code looks like as follows:

```py
  # ...
  def get_request(self, req: func.HttpRequest):
    request_body_json = req.get_json()
  # ...
```

When I pass a json array as request body (like `[{"key1": "value1"}, {"key2": "value2"}]`) of the Azure Function activity, `ValueError` occurs.

However, when I pass the same json array to Web activity, the error does not occur. The Web activity calls the same Python code as Azure Function activity.

Why am I not be able to post json array from Azure Function activity at Azure Data Factory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and the below process worked for me:
Firstly, I have reproduced in web activity and I have succeeded in my attempt with your code as below:

[image]

When I tried with Function Activity i have got the error.

Function Activity in adf do not pass the body as Json it passes as Text. so, we need to use an array variable for that.

So, I have set a variable as below:

[image]

After Set Variable, then I have created an azure function activity as below:

```
{

"rithwik":@{variables('emo')}

}
```

[image]

Then in function code:

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    request_body_json = req.get_json()
    return func.HttpResponse(f"Received the message: {request_body_json['rithwik']}", status_code=200)
```

`request_body_json['rithwik']` as it will print the Value.

Output:
[image]

**Reference:**

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/923069/issue-while-passing-content-as-a-body-to-azure-fun
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/917644/how-to-pass-string-output-of-set-varibale-activity